# err 111 Flutter VS Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, flutter, apache, http, exception

I'm currently working on a project where i got stuck on connecting Laravel 8 with Flutter. When I run the API normal inside Postman, everything works perfectly once I try it inside Flutter i got the follow error.

```
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = [IP Address Server], port = 43798
```

I don't understand, the code is fine. When I Call the API inside another laravel project then it works perfectly, only when I call it in Flutter i got this error.

What can it be. We don't run it locally it is **server -> flutter**

Flutter code:

```
    Future<User> getUser(url) async {
    print("here");
    var params = {
      "id": "01142",
    };

    Uri uri =
        Uri.parse(url);
    uri.replace(queryParameters: params);

    final response = await http.get(
      uri,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': "*/*",
        'connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'host': 'ipv4',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.

      user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      print("NEW USER");
      print(user);
      return user;
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load user');
    }
  }
```

Comment: please show me a code when you getting error

Comment: @SaidKurt I added the Flutter code for you :D

Comment: and what is your final `Uri uri` before calling `await http.get`? try to `print('uri: $uri')` and check the logs

Comment: @pskink Here is the URL:  http://xx.xx.xx.xx/client/public/api/students/show

Comment: tried to call your `getUser()` method from [unit test](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction)?

Comment: @pskink My get users works perfectly. I already did it with postman and another laravel application outside my scope. And it all worked perfectly. UnitTest gives good result on saving data and calling data from getUser/Student so that isn't the problem. The problem is that connection refused from Flutter.

Comment: can you `ping xx.xx.xx.xx` from the emulator / device you are running your code?

Comment: @pskink     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 27ms, Maximum = 117ms, Average = 60ms

Comment: and what about trying to connect on that port `43798`? i dont know, `telnet` / `curl` etc...

Comment: @pskink Weird, I got on telnet connection refused, also on the port number but as well on normal IP.

Comment: *"The problem is that connection refused from Flutter."* - so it is box 'networking' problem, not flutter's

Comment: @pskink I understand. I'm looking at the server now. Better serverside then code side, because All code tests are running perfectly. Thanks for the help!